# Alternative(s) to DataBinder.Eval for .NET Framework Client Profile?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-client-profile, databinder

I would like to have the functionality of [DataBinder.Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyw1zse1) (i.e., perform runtime databinding); however, DataBinder.Eval is defined in the System.Web assembly, which is not available on the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

I am wondering if there is an alternative in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile assemblies, or if maybe a Mono DLL file might have something with this functionality.

If not, I may have to copy the code for DataBinder.Eval using Reflector, but I would prefer using an existing method if possible.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Can you use one of .Net's standard data-binding systems?

Comment: You might check out [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.90).aspx) in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.